# Send email with custom "from" address

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gmail

In my open source and free online application, the tool allows people to send emails to their audience. For this purpose, I use java mail API and Gmail SMTP. However, when sending, the "from" address always is my account that I use to authenticate into Gmail and not the user's email address. This leads to a lot of confusion and problems.

I understand Gmail's philosophy to not allow this (to prevent abuse), but it is a serious limitation from my app's perspective.

Are there any free/ cheap online email services other than Gmail that allow programmatic interfacing and allow programs to send emails with a specified "from" address?

Comment: What Google does is a Good Thing(TM) since a forged `From` header is a common sign for spam.

Comment: @Tichodroma, not disputing that at all! But because some people may spam, genuine needs are getting hampered. My question really is not whether what google does is right or not, my question is if there are alternatives :)

Comment: I doubt that this is a genuine need.

Comment: ??????????????? on what grounds, may I ask?

Comment: Your user has an email account at provider example.com. If you want to send an email for user@example.com, go to the SMTP server of example.com, login as user, and send the email. That's the way it is done. Everything else is an open gateways hopefully blocked by any spam filter.

Comment: The hosting service for your application should provide you with a SMTP server that you should use to send emails. But as mentioned, forging `From` is the most common sign of spam and most likely such emails will be filtered out by spam filters or SMTP servers on the route.

Comment: @PetrPudlák, thanks, fair point. If you want to add your comment as an answer, I can "accept" it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosting service for your application should provide you with a SMTP server that you should use to send emails. But as mentioned, forging `From` is the most common sign of spam and most likely such emails will be filtered out by spam filters or SMTP servers on the route.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set the reply-to address for the email so that the users still reply to the correct email address?

Therefore you keep the from address as your gmail address but set the reply-to address to be the users address.

Something like:

```
msg.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress("someone@yahoo.com"));
```

Comment: yea that's already done :). The user's complained that their audience was getting emails from the application's account and not theirs, and so emails were getting missed. But guess it cant be helped